# Transactions per second vs Time for one transaction in Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

The Hyperledger on paper states that it supports 3500 transactions per second 
But what is the time it takes to commit/execute one transaction? 
is it equal to one block time? 
can we use Hyperledger for a realtime application that needs a transaction to be done within 100 ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3500 transactions per second means that on average, 3500 transactions were created by some clients and then appeared in some next newly created block within one second.

It can be that several blocks were created in that second.

You can't use Fabric, or any other consensus mechanism that uses IP networks for a real time application, simply because that if the network transmission can be delayed for more than 100ms.

You can, however - make the consensus service in Fabric use low batch timeouts (say, of 10ms) and then blocks would be formed on a frequent basis and you'll have a transaction latency less than 100ms on average.

Comment: are you saying that I can't use fabric for real-time applications? 
or if I make consensus service in Fabric use low batch timeouts then I use it for a real-time application?
it would be great if you can share an article if any on how to do this.
thanks

Comment: It will work most of the time if the network is fast, but networks are many times unreliable and you will exceed your real time guarantees.

Comment: do you have any ratio?

Comment: What are the typical implications of making batch timeouts lower? Orderer performance? CPU utilization?

Comment: mostly lower latency when the traffic isn't saturating the maximum block size. If you have B bytes incoming per second, and the maximum block size is M, then without a batch timeout, the orderer will cut blocks every M/B seconds. But sometimes you want latency to be lower than that, so you set a batch timeout to cut blocks every min(M/B, timeout).